# In Elixir, is there a shorthand way to access tuple items inside shorthand anonymous function notation?

Tags: elixir

The most common scenario I encounter this with is with Maps. Here is the full anonymous notation:

```
Enum.sort(some_map, fn {k1,_v1}, {k2,_v2} -> k1 <= k2 end)
```

Here is shorthand:

```
Enum.sort(some_map, &( elem(&1,0) <= elem(&2,0) ))
```

Scala has [this nice nifty notation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html) for tuple items by index. Does Elixir have something similar or are we stuck using [Kernel.elem/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.html#elem/2) ?

Comment: Sorting maps makes a little sense because maps with ≥ 32 keys are not sorted by definition.

Comment: I'm not aware of a better shorthand, but you may prefer to use `Enum.sort_by/3` instead of `Enum.sort/2` so you only have to do the mapping once: `Enum.sort_by(some_map, &elem(&1, 0))`; or you could even make a named function for it: `Enum.sort_by(some_map, &map_key/1)` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3

Comment: If you need a map where keys are sorted (without needing to sort on the fly every time you enumerate on it), you might want to try a different data structure which keeps keys sorted, like [`:gb_trees`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gb_trees.html). Of course it depends on your use case. (Just mentioning, since this is not directly related to your question)

Comment: Yep, as commented below Enum.sort_by/3 appears to have more concise syntax, thank you. And sabiwara's comment looks promising for a sorted map. Another awesome Java data structure which I'd like to see in Elixir is the LinkedHashMap whihch maintains insertion order: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @cppProgrammer while this doesn't exist in the standard library AFAIK, you might be interested by the Aja library which has a fairly optimized [`OrdMap`](https://github.com/sabiwara/aja#ordered-maps-aordmap) (disclosure: I'm the author).

Comment: @sabiwara that is beautiful! Love it. I'll consider including your library. So OrdMap appears to respect insertion order which is very cool; have you considered an implementation which accepts a custom sort function so all insertions are sorted by that rule instead like java's OrderedMap?

Comment: Or...perhaps that breaks the functional paradigm since adding such behavior to a type instead of using separate utility functions is an OOP approach. Wonder if that has anything to do with the decision to avoid more advanced data structures in the standard library?

Comment: @cppProgrammer I'm not very familiar with Java, but this seems like an interesting data structure. The implementation would probably look quite different from the insertion order though, maybe something like a struct with 3 fields: a map, a gb_tree, a function, and then implement all functions from the `Map` module to do the book-keeping. That would be an interesting experiment, but it might end up being less efficient than using a plain map + sorting on the fly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options have for accessing tuples are [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.html#elem/2), [`Access.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#elem/1) and pattern matching. However, the [`Enum.sort_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#sort_by/3) function does the job less verbosely than `Enum.sort/2`.

```
Enum.sort_by(map, &elem(&1, 1))                # Kernel.elem/2
Enum.sort_by(map, fn {key, _value} -> key end) # pattern matcing
```

And in case you don't mind the map values, that can be even shorter.

```
map |> Map.keys() |> Enum.sort()
```

Comment: Sorting by `fn {key, _value} -> key end` is literally the same as `& &1` because tuples are sorted by their values, left to right. `Enum.sort(map)` would do the exactly the same, but beware it returns **a list** back.

Comment: Thank you, indeed Enum.sort_by/3 as you and others point out is shorter. Also Aleksei makes a good point.

Comment: Thank you, indeed Enum.sort_by/3 as you and others point out is shorter. Also Aleksei makes a good point. Also a) In this case yes I am attempting to extract the list key-value pairs into a list (keys are strings so cannot be a keyword list), but b) In general to transform to a sorted map (like Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) has is a better solution so sabiwara's comment may be a great way to go.

Comment: Can also implement an operator:

def tuple ~> index, do: elem(tuple, index)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a shorthand way to access tuple items inside shorthand anonymous function notation?

No.

> Are we stuck using [Kernel.elem/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Kernel.html#elem/2) ?

Yes.

Comment: Technically, we also can implement `Access` for tuples, but tuples are not supposed to be accessed by index.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin  Considering`Access` is a behaviour, not a protocol, and seems to only be written to handle maps, keyword lists, and structs, I don't see how it would be possible to implement `Access` for tuples.

Comment: Ouch, indeed. My fault.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I learned from the `Access` source code that `%module` can be used to match the struct name: `%foo{} = 1..3; foo` => `Range` 

Comment: Also pinned: `foo = Foo; %^foo{} = %Foo{}`. https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2018/02/23/pattern-matching-on-dynamic-struct-types

Comment: lol Thank you for the concise answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I am currently using: Implement an operator.

```
def tuple ~> index, do: elem(tuple, index)
```

Then you can easily access with x~>n and make super compact code like this:

```
data = [{["root", "dir1"], 100}, {["root", "dir2"], 200}]
data |> Enum.map(& {Enum.join(&1~>0, "."), &1~>1}) |> Map.new
```